# Will anything ever use the 64 bit applicationHost.config on windows server 2008 R2?

Tags: iis, wow64, applicationhost

Will anything ever use the 64 bit applicationHost.config on windows server 2008 R2?
Since w3wp is 32 bit, does the 64 bit file even matter? Should I go out of my way to make sure they are kept in sync?

Answer (score 0):

First, there is only a applicationHost.config at `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config`, and that one is for 64 bit. There is no 32 bit one at `%windir%\sysWOW64\inetsrv\config`. If you do see a 32 bit one it is not used by IIS. Thus, there is no need to "keep in sync".

Second, IIS on 64 bit Windows is 64 bit (http.sys driver as well as IIS core components in %windir%\system32\inetsrv). You might see some application pools are configured as 32 bit, and their worker processes are 32 bit w3wp.exe, but that's only the part of IIS hosting web applications. The majority of IIS is still fully running in 64 bit.

Comment: %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config; Open the file with notepad (64 bit process), then open the same file with a 32 bit process like notepad++, the files are different.

Comment: What you opened in Notepad++ is obvious not the IIS configuration file, but something else. 32 bit editors (such as Notepad++, or 32 bit Notepad at `%windir%\sysWOW64\notepad.exe`) are not valid for 64 bit files under system paths, as Windows WOW64 redirects them automatically.

Comment: I know, but IIS (w3wp.exe*32)is a 32 bit process; so which one will it read?

Comment: w3wp.exe (no matter 32 bit or 64 bit) does not read the configuration at all. The worker processes read the default configuration file at all. They in fact read from a private cache, where effective configuration is extracted and persisted. That's the implementation details you should not care about.